# remove appended data with button click id by id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, append, local-storage

I append a dynamic button and want when I click button Related data will be remove

```
async function DataShow()
{
for (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++)
     {
      x = localStorage.key(i);
      if (x !='debugbar-time-new' && x !='debugbar-time' && x!='__mycart')
      {
        item = await JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(x))
        $("#table_data").append('<tr> <td>'+item['_id']+'</td> <td>'+item['title']+'</td><td><button class="btn btn-primary remove" value="'+item['_id']+'">remove</button></td></tr>')
      }
    }
}
```

there is my remove functionality

```
$( "#table_data" ).on('click','.remove',function(){
var item_id = $('#table_data button').val()
window.localStorage.removeItem(item_id);
  });
```

Problem is when I click button Button always fetch last element id
I also see with inspect element all button have it's own id
I also try `$('this').val()` but it not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `this` keyword within the event handler to refer to the element which raised the event. In your case you can use this to get the `value` property:

```
$("#table_data").on('click', '.remove', function() {
  var item_id = this.value;
  window.localStorage.removeItem(item_id);
});
```